# A different PDE solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $$u_t = u_{xx} - u$$ with $u(0,t)=0$, $u(\pi,t)=1$, and $u(x,0)=0$.

---

If we let $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-\frac{x}{\pi},$ we have

$$\begin{cases} v_t(x,t)=v_{xx}(x,t)- v(x,t) - \frac{x}{\pi},\\ v(0,t)=v(\pi,t)=0, \\ v(x,0) =\frac{-x}{\pi}.\end{cases}$$

We can consider the homogenous equation $v_t=v_xx-v.$ If $v(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ then

$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} +1= \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$$

With some calculations I got

$$u(x,t)= \frac{x}{\pi}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 (-1)^{n+1} e^{n^2 (-t)-t} \left(-e^{\left(n^2+1\right) t}+n^2+2\right)}{\pi n \left(n^2+1\right)}\sin(n x)$$

I am looking a different solution if we assume $v=e^{t} u$

Comment: Did you try $v = e^t u$? If so, where are you stuck?